# how to count every table data in database?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
def show_catalog_stats():
  return(spark.sql("""SHOW DATABASES""").show(),
         spark.sql("""SHOW TABLES IN NbaDb""").show(),
         spark.table([tableName]).count()
         
 )
 

show_catalog_stats()

+---------+
|namespace|
+---------+
|  default|
|    nbadb|
+---------+

+---------+------------+-----------+
|namespace|   tableName|isTemporary|
+---------+------------+-----------+
|    nbadb|       games|      false|
|    nbadb|games_detail|      false|
|    nbadb|     players|      false|
|    nbadb|     ranking|      false|
|    nbadb|       teams|      false|
+---------+------------+-----------+
```

here is my code I need to return table name from database and count.output like  but it doesn't return count for each table what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take the column tableName values from the query `SHOW TABLES IN NbaDb` and perform a count on each of them, while iterating.

Comment: how it is syntax?